# Prevent TinyMCE from removing section tag

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, rich-text-editor

Im using TinyMCE richtext editor on Umbraco website. but when i tried to add any section tag and save, it will remove it automatically.

```
Eg : <section class='cls'>test content</section>
```

Anyone knows how to prevent it ?

i've tried => extended_valid_elements: 'section[!class]' also not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Allow the section tag with class attribute by going to config/tinymceconfig.config.
Look for `validElements` setting and include "section[class]".

You might also need to retouch and re-save your web.config in order for new settings to take effect.

Comment: Hi i've manage to fixed it . but i got another issue.
i've this a tag with span inside.

  `eg:<a href='xxx' class='xxx'><span class='xxx'>test</span></a>`

after i save span tag content goes outside like this :
  `<a href='xxx' class='xxx'></a><span class='xxx'>test</span>`

do know why its like that ?

Comment: That sometimes happen if you have incorrect html syntax. Are you sure you have placed it correctly?